# Why is Basic Auth client default behaviour to require 401 before sending credentials?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, wget, basic-authentication

I'm currently trying to understand some technical implications of using HTTP Basic Auth for an HTTP API sketch.

What I noticed is that both the [C# HTTP Web Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well as `wget` will - by default - send a request *without* credentials first, resulting in a `401` from the server and only then send the basic authentication info. (Thanks to SO auto suggestions, [it seems browsers do it the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515098/send-basic-auth-by-default-rather-than-wait-for-http-401).)

You can get wget to always send it via `--auth-no-challenge` but it's not the default.

The [HttpWebRequest object will *always* request a 401 first, unless you manually assemble the authentication header](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/feroze_daud/2004/07/12/httpwebrequest-and-preauthentication/). (Even with the `PreAuthentication` option.)

Is there a specific reason (in the HTTP spec) for this? It seems weird that these "developer centered tools" will do the authentication dacne when I already specify that I want to to basic auth + user + passwd?

---

Adding a quote from the (hopefully) relevant [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt): (emph. mine)

> A user agent that wishes to authenticate itself with an origin
>   server -- *usually, **but not necessarily**, after receiving a 401*
>   (Unauthorized) -- MAY do so by including an Authorization header field
>   with the request.

Comment: FWIW, the relevant specs are RFC 7235 and 7617; but I don't think these have a better answer.